# Is there anywhere else to see my app's crashes other than Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, watchkit, xcode9

In the project organizer, one project I'm working on hasn't shown any crashes since I updated to Xcode 9. All of the previously shown crashes disappeared too. I have Fabric in the app, but I'm testing mostly on Apple Watch and Fabric doesn't support watch crashes. I submitted the bug to Apple's Bug Reporter several weeks ago but haven't received a response. Is there anywhere or any way else I can get crash reports, specifically for WatchKit?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try on your phone going to Settings -> Privacy -> Analytics -> Analytics Data. Scroll through the Data and look for crashes related to your application.